# BIGINT vs combined ( tinyint, int ) for Large auto_increment key?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am designing a website and have a table which dealing with lot of inserts. On each month this table will get at least 50 million records.

So currently I am using bigint unsgined data type as the primary key of this table.

```
CREATE TABLE `class`.`add_contact_details`
( 
`con_id` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
`add_id_ref` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, 
`con_name` VARCHAR(200), 
`con_email` VARCHAR(200), 
`con_phone` VARCHAR(200), 
`con_fax` VARCHAR(200), 
`con_mailbox` VARCHAR(500), 
`con_status_show_email` TINYINT(1), 
`con_status_show_phone` TINYINT(1), 
`con_status_show_fax` TINYINT(1), 
`con_status_show_mailbox` TINYINT(1), 
PRIMARY KEY (`con_id`) ) ENGINE=INNODB CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_swedish_ci;
```

So by doing a big research I found that most of the people are worry about using BIGINT because it is memory consuming and need lot of space.

So I found an article that describing a alternate for that. Here it is

"You could use a combined ( tinyint, int ) key. The tinyint would start at, and default to, 1. IF the int value is ever about to overflow, you change the tinyint's default value to 2, and reset the int value to 1. You can create code that runs every day, or on another applicable schedule, which checks for that condition and makes that change if needed."

So it make sense right? So Is there anybody who is using this? 
What should I use by considering the performance?

Is there any alternative enterprice level solution for this?

Comment: IMO I think using long won't add that much overhead, it's easier to maintain and to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stick with the `BIGINT`.  You do save two or three bytes using the dual key, but you do pay for it.

1. References to the table need to use two keys instead of one, so all foreign key relationships are more complicated.
2. `where` clauses to find a single row are much more complicated.  Consider the difference between:

   ```
    where id in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
   ```

   and

   ```
    where id_part1 = 0 and id_part2 = 1 or
          id_part1 = 0 and id_part2 = 2 or
          . . .
   ```
3. The step to increment the first part is no automatic, requiring either manual intervention or the overhead of a trigger.
4. This reminds me (in a bad way) of segmented memory architectures that were in vogue 20+ years ago.  Be happy the computer can understand 64-bit keys with no problems.

Comment: Thank you Gordon Linoff. Well explained.

Answer (score 0):

BIGINT needs 8 bytes of storage so 50 million records is 400 MB per month which shouldn't be an issue at all.

We are running databases (on DB2) with a couple of TB on a single server.

The only thing you should consider for querying by PK is putting an index on that field.

best regards

Romeo Kienzler

Comment: Thank you Kienzler. But I declared auto_incremnt Id as the primary key of the table. It makes it an index field right?

Comment: Yes u r right, nearly all rdbms create an index on the pk field, sorry!